# Do I need to have key/value "pairs" to make use of hash tables?

Tags: hash, hashmap

A basic question regarding hash tables. Consider a simple case of replacing an array of integers by a hash table. what are key/value pairs here? A pair doesn't make sense here if I'm not wrong.

For example, I would like to map integers to an array of size 10(buckets from 0 to 9). 
Consider an hash function which just takes mod 10 on the input.
For instance, element 23 will go to the bucket of 3 as 23 % 10 = 3.

As per my understanding, 23 is the key and 3 is the hash value corresponding to it. Isn't 23 a 'value'?

Comment: In that case the key is the index in the array and the value is the value.  Not a very useful substitution unless you want a sparse array.

Comment: Sorry,  but you use data structures to fit some use. What is the use you are trying to apply it to, i.e. why do you want to replace an array of integers with a hashtable? Hashtables are always a key/value store, but sometimes you can just ignore a value, setting it to a constant, e.g. `true`. Also, if you tag with a specific language, we could suggest more appropriate built-in structures such as sets (which are commonly built on hashtables, in the very way I described above).

Comment: Thanks adam and Amadan. I was just trying to understand the fundamentals of hash tables. I have added a use case in the question. please clear my doubts.

Comment: Which language and/or framework are you asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `23` is the key. The hash of the key, in your case `3`, determines the bucket. The value is what you put in the bucket, associated with the key `23`. For example, in many languages, you would write:

```
my_hashtable[23] = "Valerie"
```

which would create a key-value pair `(23, "Valerie")` and stuff it in a certain bucket of `my_hashtable`.

The purpose of a hashtable is to associate keys and values, and allow lookup in an efficient way. Buckets and hashes are an implementation detail (the optimal one, so everyone is using them, but still an implementation detail, and thus irrelevant to the user of a hashtable).

As I noted in the comment, if you need sets instead, most languages do support them as well. Many will use a hashtable it in the background to do it, but that, as well, is an implementation detail.